# How to get access to property inside ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Here is my ActionFilter:

```
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public LogAttribute(ILoggerFactory logger)
    {
        Logger = logger.CreateLogger<LogAttribute>();
    }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }

    public ILogger Logger { get; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
        UserId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        Path = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}[{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]";
        Logger.LogDebug($"{Path} started. User(id): {UserId}.");
    }
}
```

I want to use UserId and Path properties in other places of my controllers. Is there laconic way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I agree with Serge, it can be better to use BaseController for this task**. There are no ways to do it clearly with an attribute.

For example:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly ILogger<T> Logger;

    protected BaseController(ILogger<T> logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
    protected string UserId { get; set; }
    protected string Path { get; set; }

    [NonAction]
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        UserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        Path = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}[{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]";
        Logger.LogDebug($"{Path} started. User(id): {UserId}.");
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController<HomeController>
{
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger): base(logger)
    {
    }
}
```

Or just use *override OnActionExecuting* in your specific controller

```
    public class HomeController: Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private string _userId;
        private string _path;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [NonAction]
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            _userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            _path = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value} 
            [{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]";
            _logger.LogDebug($"{Path} started. User(id): {UserId}.");
        }
    }
```

I'll show you some minuses of using an attribute for this.

1.You can use *HttpContext.Items* which implements *IDictionary<object,object>* and is accessable for request (lifetime as scope). But for this you have to use Resource filter.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SampleLogAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
    {
        public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Items["path"] = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path}[{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]";
            context.HttpContext.Items["userId"] = "SomeUserIdFromResource";
        }

        public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

Then you can get it from your controller using OnActionExecuting

```
    private string _path;
    private string _userId;
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        _path = HttpContext.Items["path"] as string;
        _userId = HttpContext.Items["userId"] as string;
    }
```

The main reason not to do it - you must know that your filter set values to *Items* and always create them in controller.

2.You can set private values using reflection in your attribute

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var controller = context.Controller;
    var path = controller.GetType().GetField("_path", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    path?.SetValue(controller, $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path}[{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]");
    var userId = controller.GetType().GetField("_userId", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    userId?.SetValue(controller, "SomeUserId");
}
```

You must understand if you forget create essential variables - you cannot access them.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question right... We're trying to pull UserId and Path (maybe query string) out of current Http Requet ?

If so, try this

```cs
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var userId = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); // claims type depend on how we configure authentication. But many default fall into this constants.
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        var queryString = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        //... Do whatever we need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create basecontroller

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
      public BaseController(ILoggerFactory logger)
    {
        Logger = logger.CreateLogger<LogAttribute>();
    }

    protected string UserId { get; set; }

    protected string Path { get; set; }

    protected ILogger Logger { get; }
    
        [NonAction]
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
       var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as 
         ControllerActionDescriptor;
            var controllerName = controllerActionDescriptor?.ControllerName;
            var actionName = controllerActionDescriptor?.ActionName;
        UserId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        Path = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}[{context.HttpContext.Request.Method}]";
        Logger.LogDebug($"{Path} started. User(id): {UserId}.");
    }
}
```